# Why does "Build Agent Folder" on TFS 2013 open to local machine?

Tags: c#, build-definition

If I try to create a new build definition in Visual Studio, on the "Source Settings" tab under the "Build Agent Folder" window, if I click the text field that shows a button that displays a window that allows you to input a directory path from your local machine. Why does it do this?

From what I understand, the "Build Agent Folder" is the directory on the build machine that your project is being pulled to in order to be built. Not your local machine, which is why `$(SourceDir)` routes to `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` on the build machine.

Comment: The reason it does that is "because Microsoft designed it that way". I'm voting to close this question because it's too broad to be answered. My guess would be that the workspace mapping control is the same for both defining a local workspace and defining a build, so it behaves the same way for both contexts, even though it's not necessarily correct behavior in one of them.